# How to list directory contents in Ruby Scripting?

Tags: ruby

I found the powerful module [FileUtils](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html). But cannot seem to find the function that lists the contents ie ls.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a method that returns an array, then `Dir.entries` is what you want.

```
Dir.entries(dirname) -> (array)
```

This will list out a users home directory and return an array

```
Dir.entries(ENV['HOME'])
=> [".",
 "..",
 ".bash_history",
 ".bash_profile",
 ".bashrc",
 ".CFUserTextEncoding",
 ".cheat",
 ".DS_Store",
 ".gem",
 ".gemrc",
 ".gist", ... etc.
```

The other method `Dir.open` returns a directory object rather than an array

```
 Dir.open(string) -> aDir
```

using `Dir.open` on a users home directory gives you

```
 Dir.open(ENV['HOME'])
=> #<Dir:/Users/Brian>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer was [`Dir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html):

```
d = Dir.open '/home/dan/directoroy'
```

`d` is an array of the contents of that directory.

Comment: What Ruby version? That won't work in 2.0, where `Dir.open '/tmp'` returns a Dir object.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3.  And yes I don't think I was accurate. I just thought it was since `d.each` served my purpose.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. `open` returns a dir object and `entries` returns an array

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Glob

In Ruby 2.0, you can use [Dir#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries) to retrieve all the files in a directory, or a glob such as [Dir['/tmp/*']](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) or [Dir.glob '/tmp/*'](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) if you want finer-grained control over what entries are returned, or if you want to retrieve files/directories recursively.